# Add a item at top for each day in fullCalendar that is total of all event amount

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Simply I have added all events in fullcalendar with event Amount and I want to add a item at top of the day that is the total of all event amount. Or if any dayrender event available that is corresponding running for each day events.

Please give me any suggestion...

Comment: Where does your data come from? Database?

Comment: the data come from database. the code for fetching data in aspx form within static web method and return list to json. json shows the Event in Full Calendar.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question you can use the ajax success callback to loop through all events and get the total, then use jquery/javascript to apply to element. I'm not sure what you want in the second part of your question but I think you should be able to use the same method to achieve it.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: {
        url: '/myfeed.php',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            // loop through events to get total
            // you may need to return the response
        }
    }
});
```